# How to learn a spesific table's number of rows that exists in all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @Db_Name VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @TempCommand VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @RowCount INT
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases;
OPEN MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Db_Name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
SELECT @RowCount=COUNT(*) FROM @Db_Name.Test
IF @Db_Name<>'master' AND @Db_Name<>'model' AND @Db_Name<>'msdb' AND
@Db_Name<>'tempdb' AND @Db_Name<>'CAP' AND @Db_Name<>'icden' AND @Db_Name<>'EASYEVENT'
AND @Db_Name<>'IDKK2' 
BEGIN
PRINT @Db_Name
SELECT @Command='INSERT INTO '+@Db_Name+'.dbo.Test'+ 
'SELECT TOP 15 NEWID(), TestCode, TestDescription, TestComment, Test_TestCategoryId,
TestIsPreliminaryStudy, TestIsFieldwork, TestIsAllInstitutionUnit,
TestStatus, GETDATE(), dbo.fn_GetSite() FROM icden..Test ORDER BY TestCode';
EXEC sp_executesql @Command;
END
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Db_Name;
END
CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
```

I want to execute this command for all databases in my server. Before do this, I must learn how many rows there are in my 'Test' table that exists in each database. I tried the above script but it didn't work.

Comment: Try the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but I have already done this. I wrote EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?];' before SELECT @RowCount=COUNT(*) FROM Test but It was executed only current database.